# Trace the intersection of the perpendicular tangents for a convex curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves

An intuition that I thought of about a year ago, but my level does not allow me to prove it. I think it needs advanced tools to prove it, or just a counterexample to refute it. Who can help, please, thank you.

The locus of the point of [intersection of the perpendicular tangents](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoptic_(geometry)) of a convex curve is the convex curve

Of course, the intuition is only in this direction and does not constitute an obligation, as the cardioid is a concave curve. Despite this, tracing the perpendicular tangents to it gives a circle

Comment: I think that if the intuition is correct for general curves, then the parabola and the tangents perpendicular to it that are straight can be overlooked, which is the evidence for the parabola

Comment: Does this apply for a circle? If so, can you explain how?

Comment: Of course, it applies to the circle. Tracing the perpendicular tangents to the circle gives another circle, which is the circle surrounding a square whose sides touch the first circle. Imagine that you rotate this square around the small circle so that it is always contiguous with it, so the vertices of the square will remain on the same circle surrounding it.

Comment: Ah, so when you say "... is the convex curve", what you mean is "is a scaled version of the convex curve", as opposed to "is THE original convex curve"? (May be a language issue?)

Comment: Not a miniature version Tracing the perpendicular tangents of the ellipse does not give a larger version of the ellipse but rather a circle Curves that give a circle are few and defined

Comment: so you mean "is a (different) convex curve"? Again, my issue is with the word "the", which means "the original one that is the subject of the sentence". Just trying to make sense of what you're saying here, so the more examples you can add (in the body), the better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146754/discussion-between---and-calvin-lin).

Comment: I think you should correct your text to "The locus of the point of intersection of the perpendicular tangents of a convex curve is A convex curve".

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I tried to convince OP of that (EG See the discussion in chat), and their reply was "I read and write using google translator, so sympathies may differ between the two languages ​​in imprecise terms, but with a sentence like this you get the intuition".  In OP's other questions, they said "I don't know English and am using google translate to write my proof, thanks for noticing", so unfortunately having a discussion about language semantics would be tough. $\quad$ I've also tried asking them to add more examples, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the intuition is wrong. The locus of intersection of the perpendicular tangents of the curves of the figure $x^{2n}+y^{2n}=r^{2n} ،n>1$

[image]

You can view the article: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Construction-of-the-orthoptic-of-the-Fermat-curve-x4-y41documentclass12ptminimal_fig8_337743100